# JQuery - Check a value

Tags: jquery, html

I have a HTML likes this

```
 <ul id="changeColr">
    <li>100</li>
    <li>200</li>
    <li>300</li>
</ul>
<button>Click Me</button>
```

if a `li` contains a value of 200, I want to use JQuery to change the color of 200 to red.

Here is my JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        if ($('#changeColr li').attr('200')) {
            $(this).css('color', 'red');
        } else {
            $(this).css('color', '')
        }
    });
});
```

But it doesn't work out.
Please give me a hand.  Thanks

Comment: `if( $('#changeColr li').attr('200'))` changed with `if( $('#changeColr li').text('200'))`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tLYU3/ check this

Answer (score 3):

You can use [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to filter the element with specific text.

> **:contains** Select all elements that contain the specified text, [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/5degY/)**

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('#changeColr li:contains(200)').css('color', 'red');
});
```

**Edit** to pass the text of element to filter you can make the selector by concatenating selector string.

```
var text = "200";
$('#changeColr li:contains('+ text +')').css('color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('button').click(function () {
        //iterate through each li elements and sets its color
        $('#changeColr li').css('color', function () {
            //if the text in the current li is 300 then return red else ''
            return $.trim($(this).text()) == '300' ? 'red' : '';
        })
    }); //end click
}); //end ready
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CnVFS/)

Answer (score 0):

Try below :

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
        {
            $('button').click(
                function()
                    {
                       $("#changeColr li").each(function(){
                         if($(this).text()=="200")
                              $(this).css('color','red');
                      });
                    }
            );  //end click
        }
);
```

Comment: Thank everyone very much! Every method is working well!  I have to vote for everyone, but it doesn't let me!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to your css:

```
.highlight {
    color: red;
}
```

then you can use **[:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)** selector to target only the list item that cotain `200` inside its text along with **[.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)** to toggle the `highlight` class on button click:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('button').click(function () {
        $('#changeColr li:contains("200")').toggleClass('highlight');
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k6zsb/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("button").click(function(){//try to use on.('click') though
$("#changeColr").find("li").each(function(){
if($(this).text()=="200"){
$(this).css('color','red');
}
});
```

Comment: If you want to make rep, study the [best voted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669909/jquery-check-a-value/23669963#23669963) to this question ;) I'm out of votes for today, otherwise I'd upvote Felix's answer too.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is modified slightly to iterate for loop on li

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        $('button').click(
            function()
            {                $('#changeColr li').each(function(){
                if( $(this).html() == '200')
                {
                    $(this).css('color', 'red');
                }
                else
                {
                    $(this).css('color', '')
                }

            });
                        }
        );  //end click
    }
);  //end ready
```

Refer demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/chiragvidani/SCdc3/)